# How to ensure that a ResultSet includes rows for "missing" observations

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a ResultSet table shown below:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+
| test_date  | upload_kbps        | download_kbps      | latency | network_operator_name |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+
| 2017-04-02 |  19.12741903076923 | 44.614721153846155 | 32.1250 | Alcatel               |           
| 2017-03-31 |  18.30683616557377 | 44.294387978142076 | 34.7432 | Alcatel               |
| 2017-03-31 | 20.643555595555555 |  50.99801587301587 | 32.1640 | Vodafone              |
```

I want to modify the ResultSet for further use where while I add a row into the ResultSet like so:

```
    +------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+
    | test_date  | upload_kbps        | download_kbps      | latency | network_operator_name |
    +------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+
    | 2017-04-02 |  19.12741903076923 | 44.614721153846155 | 32.1250 | Alcatel               |   
    | 2017-04-02 |  0                 | 0                  | 0       | Vodafone              |        
    | 2017-03-31 |  18.30683616557377 | 44.294387978142076 | 34.7432 | Alcatel               |
    | 2017-03-31 | 20.643555595555555 |  50.99801587301587 | 32.1640 | Vodafone              |
```

The logic behind this is to basically add a null row for that telecom where on that day, a speedtest was not done for it. For further clarification: the reason i need to do this is because the table in MySQL db does not record a row/entry for tests not done, hence the lack of a row in my original ResultSet, hence the need for me to add a 'NULL/0' row to reflect the lack of test for that telco, on that day. I don't have direct access to that database to modify the entries currently so this was the best I can think of.

Any idea how I can do this? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add rows to the ResultSet after the fact. AFAIK, we can't do that. Instead we need to construct our SQL query so that it will produce the "extra" rows we need.

So if we have a table named "test" and

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY test_date DESC, network_operator_name
```

produces

```
test_date   upload_kbps       download_kbps     latency  network_operator_name
----------  ----------------  ----------------  -------  ---------------------
2017-04-02  19.1274190307692  44.6147211538461   32.125  Alcatel              
2017-03-31  18.3068361655737   44.294387978142  34.7432  Alcatel              
2017-03-31  20.6435555955555  50.9980158730158   32.164  Vodafone
```

then we can start with a query to produce a row for every combination of `test_date` and `network_operator_name`

```sql
SELECT test_date, network_operator_name
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT network_operator_name FROM test) unique_operators
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT test_date FROM test) unique_dates
```

which gives us

```
test_date   network_operator_name
----------  ---------------------
2017-03-31  Alcatel              
2017-03-31  Vodafone             
2017-04-02  Alcatel              
2017-04-02  Vodafone
```

Then we can LEFT JOIN that query with the actual table

```sql
SELECT 
    required_rows.test_date,
    COALESCE(test.upload_kbps, 0) AS upload_kbps,
    COALESCE(test.download_kbps, 0) AS download_kbps,
    COALESCE(test.latency, 0) AS latency,
    required_rows.network_operator_name
FROM 
    (
        SELECT test_date, network_operator_name
        FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT network_operator_name FROM test) unique_operators
            CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT test_date FROM test) unique_dates
    ) required_rows
    LEFT JOIN
    test
        ON required_rows.test_date = test.test_date 
            AND required_rows.network_operator_name = test.network_operator_name
ORDER BY required_rows.test_date DESC, required_rows.network_operator_name
```

producing

```
test_date   upload_kbps       download_kbps     latency  network_operator_name
----------  ----------------  ----------------  -------  ---------------------
2017-04-02  19.1274190307692  44.6147211538461   32.125  Alcatel              
2017-04-02                 0                 0        0  Vodafone             
2017-03-31  18.3068361655737   44.294387978142  34.7432  Alcatel              
2017-03-31  20.6435555955555  50.9980158730158   32.164  Vodafone
```

Comment: Brilliant answer that worked perfectly, plus points and my thanks for taking the time to explain it step-by-step so an mysql-newbie like me could understand it too. I really need to start thinking beyond simple select/update statements =/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NULLIF()` function of mysql. In the function you provide the variable that you test for whether speedtest was done or not. Suppose, latency would have zero when speedtest is not done on that day.

Then `NULLIF(latency,0)` would be the value for the column latency in your insert command. And so for the other columns you need to fill with **NULL** for certain conditions. This function returns **NULL** if the **1st argument** matches with **second argument**. Otherwise gives the **actual value** of the 1st argument.

Comment: I'm abit confused here. Perhaps i could clarify, there is no entry in the mysql db when no test is carried out for a telco, hence the missing row in my original ResultSet and hence the need for me to manually enter an additional 'NULL' row for that telco for that day. If i'm not mistaken from the googling i did, NULLIF() works if the mysql database table already has a zero value in its table for that telco when no test is done right?

Comment: so, you want a row with no values for a specific telco if the telco has no record for that day? do you have a fix telco list then?

Comment: Yup, i have a fixed telco list, if you mean fixed by the telcos that i will use(only the two mentioned, nothing more)

Comment: to show the report what are you using? you can load the report on that day, populating each row with values by iterating over the resultset, when you do not get any result, you can show zero on that row. if a php script is used, you can create table row combination this way. Or when you are populating the database table for entries of telco speedtest, you can insert zeros in the row for telco having no values. An entire row in the db with just telco name and other columns with NULL or zero can be achieved this way.